# Filtering data by time of the day in SAS

Tags: sas, analytics

I am a beginner in SAS and I have a data set of traffic incidents to analyse. I want to filter out the data by time of the day - all incidents before 18:00:00 . or incidents between 9:00:00 - 18:00:00

I have tried to find a suitable code, but have not had any success. Could anybody help out with this? Im using the standard SAS not enterprise guide.

Is it with a WHERE statement? if so, how do I input the time?

Answer (score 0):

I assume from your description you have a data set with a time variable and want to subset it using a hard-coded time of day.  For this, it's easiest to use a time literal with standard WHERE processing.  A time literal is a time specified in quotes followed by the `T` character.

For example, you can create something similar to the following that will subset the `times` data set but only with observations where `time` is earlier than 18:00:

```
data times_before_6pm;
    set times;
    where time < '18:00't; /* restrict to times of day earlier than 6pm */
run;
```

This assumes your times are time values and not datetime values.  If they are datetime values, you'll need to extract the time portion from it (using the TIMEPART() function, which you can do in the WHERE statement).

Hope this helps.